# Excel XML Source pane does not have button to add an XML map

Tags: excel, xmlmap

I am trying to add an XML map to an Excel workbook however my Excel doesn't have the "XML Maps" option in the XML source pane

Should look like this:

[image: Should look like this:]

Actually looks like this:

[image: Actually looks like this:]

I have no add-ins, I have repaired office, I have removed anti-virus

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance!
Clare

Comment: I have removed and reinstalled office and still have the same issue